# 'Of' in "The tomb had been robbed of its treasures."

Tags: prepositions

> The tomb had been robbed of its treasures. (Oxford Dictionary)

What should I think that this 'of' means? I know 'of' has the similar meanings to 'from' and 'about' but I am not sure which it is in this case.

Thanks and a happy new year to you!

»» I needed to know the meaning of 'of' in this usage and I've seen that question and answer but that one was about 'rob' and not explained about what I needed to know.

»» I want to comment on the 3rd answer because I like it and want to say something. I'm trying to put it in words now.. please give me some time.

Comment: I think that 'of' is used because have a possesive after, and indetifies the property, in this case should have a similar meaning as 'from'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an [entry from the American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/of), we find the following definition of "***of***", used in an example with "robbed":

> 4. So as to be separated or relieved from: ***robbed of*** one's dignity; cured of distemper.

We can understand your sentence to mean:

> The tomb had been robbed *in such a way that it was separated from* its treasures.

This usage of "***of***" also appears when we talk about "*forgiveness of sins*" or when a dismissed officer is "*relieved of command*."

Comment: Thanks. I find it's easier to understand when the sentence is passive voice. In fact all sentences given here are in passive voice. Is it more likely to be used in this way? Oxford Dictionary has an example sentence, "A last-minute goal robbed the team of victory." and it's a little awkward to me. But well, ok, I think I got it now. It can be re-writed into that the last-minute goal separated the team from victory, huh?

Answer (score 1):

Happy new year to you too. :)

> The tomb had been robbed of its treasures.

The meaning of the sentence is, "the treasures of the tomb were stolen". Though not really appropriate to replace it with "from", meaningfully, they're  the same.
**Update:** As a request from @Tetsujin, and as I think the response would be incomplete without this, I add to the post the 'revision' of the sentence using "from":

> The treasures had been robbed from the tomb.

Notice how "treasures" and "tomb" were replaced.

Comment: You couldn't just swap 'of' to 'from'. It would require a complete re-cast... "The treasures had been robbed from the tomb"

Comment: That's what I partially mentioned... "not appropriate to be replaced".

Comment: I get what you mean, but without the recast, a simple swap would [very awkwardly] tell me the tomb had been taken away, leaving the treasures behind...